# How do I do binary image classification using ImageJ?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, imagej

I want to do binary image classification and I thought ImageJ would be a good platform to do it, but alas, I am at a loss. The pseudocode for what I want to do is below. How do I implement this in ImageJ? It does not have to follow the pseudocode exactly, I just hope that gives an idea of what I want to do. (If there is a plugin or a more suitable platform that does this already, can you point me to that?)

For training:

```
train_directory = get folder from user
train_set = get all image files in train_directory

class_file = get text file from user
// each row of class_file contains image name and a "1" or "-1"
// a "1" indicates that image belongs to the positive class

model = build_model_from_train_set_and_class_file
write_model_to_output_file
// end train
```

For testing:

```
test_directory = get folder from user
test_set = get all images in test_directory
if (user wants to)
    class_file = get text file from user
    // normally for testing one would always know the class of the image
    // the if statement is just in case the user does not

model = read_model_file
output = classify_images_as_positive_or_negative
write_output_to_file
```

Note that there should not be any preprocessing done by the user: no additional set of masks, no drawings, no additional labels, etc. The algorithm must be able to figure out what is common among the training images from the training images alone and build up a model appropriately. Of course, the algorithm can do any preprocessing it wants to, it just cannot rely on that preprocesssing being done already.

I tried using CVIPtools for this but it wants a mask on all of the images to do feature extraction.